# How do I get an /HP Officejet Pro 6830 printer to work with Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, printer

I just hooked-up an HP Officejet Pro 6830 All-in-One Series printer. The install went w/o flaws. However, when printing from my computer, after printing several lines, the printing is squished together for a few lines then it prints several more lines just fine and squishes it again. Doing a test print, from the printer, seems works fine.

Any ideas of what is wrong?

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Comment: After uninstalling and reinstalling the printer driver, it now prints ~1/2 of the page, then prints the rest of the page on another sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work. After reinstalling the driver in a terminal I entered

```
hp-setup
```

From there it worked fine!